# Problema con puntero, ¿cómo hacer que funcione?

Tags: java, java-swing, punteros, class

estoy practicando haciendo un editor de texto, por ahora todo muy bien, pero me he encontrado un problema que no veo como podría ser solucionado.

Cuando se utiliza el boton safe busco que si ese fichero existe ya se guarde automaticamente y si no existe el nombre del fichero te abra el expolorador y lo guardes. Para esto cuando se abre o se guarda un fichero se le pone el nobre en un atributo que tiene la clase, pero al abrirlo y trabajar con el safe no coje el nombre si no que utiliza el predeterminado en el constructor por defecto (Aunque tras abrirlo justo si que parece que lo ha guardado). Se os ocurre por que puede estar fallando el puntero o el porque de este problema???

clase del del texto

```
    package graficos;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextFile extends JTextArea{

    private String fileName;

    public TextFile() {

        super();
        this.fileName = "aaa";

    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return this.fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String newFileName) {
        this.fileName = newFileName;
    }

}
```

clase de cargar el documento

```
package actionListeners;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.swing.JFrame;

import graficos.TextFile;
public class OpenDocument implements ActionListener{

private TextFile texto;

public OpenDocument(TextFile textArea) {
    super();
    texto = textArea;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    FileDialog windowForLoad;
    windowForLoad = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Choose file to open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    windowForLoad.setVisible(true);
    this.display(windowForLoad.getDirectory() + windowForLoad.getFile());
    System.out.println(this.texto.getFileName());

}

public void display(String fileName) {
    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            this.texto.append(line);
            this.texto.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    this.texto.setFileName(fileName);
}
```

}

y clase de save

```
package actionListeners;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import graficos.TextFile;

public class SaveAction implements ActionListener{

private TextFile text;
private String fileName;

public SaveAction(TextFile textArea) {
    super();
    this.text = textArea;
    fileName = this.text.getFileName();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Path path = Paths.get(this.fileName);
    System.out.println(this.fileName);
    if(Files.exists(path)) {
        this.save(this.fileName);

    }
    else {
        FileDialog fileChooser = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Select save file", FileDialog.SAVE );
        fileChooser.setVisible(true);
        this.save(fileChooser.getDirectory() + fileChooser.getFile());
        this.text.setFileName(fileChooser.getFile());
    }

}

public void save(String fileName) {
    try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName, false));
    writer.write(this.text.getText());
    writer.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");

    }catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

En la clase save tienes un textfield que tiene el nombre del fichero pero sin su path completo. Luego cuando llamas a actionPerformed, compruebas si existe el fichero que tienes en tu textfield, pero como esta sin el path completo, lo buscara en el directorio local donde se este ejecutando el programa. Si no existe (que sera la primera vez), lo salvas en el directorio y con el nombre elegido por el usuario,pero luego al salvarlo te dira que no existe (logicamente estara en otro directorio).
Te doy mas datos:

En la clase SaveAction  empiezas asi:

```
public class SaveAction implements ActionListener{

private TextFile text;
private String fileName;
```

Como ves tienes una referencia a la clase TextFile y un String llamado fileName. ¿ Ok ? .
En la funcion saveaction tienes lo siguiente:

```
public SaveAction(TextFile textArea) {
    super();
    this.text = textArea;
    fileName = this.text.getFileName();
}
```

Como ves, lo primero que hace es asignar a tu String filename, el valor de tu clae Filename (que le llamas text). Por cierto, no es necesario estar poniendo **this** continuamente y no tiene sentido que llames a super, ya que no heredas de nadie. La función funciona igual así:

```
 
public SaveAction(TextFile textArea) {
    text = textArea;
    fileName = text.getFileName();
}
```

El caso es que luego en la función **actionPerformed** primero compruebas si el fichero existe, de esta manera:

```
Path path = Paths.get(this.fileName);
    System.out.println(this.fileName);
    if(Files.exists(path)) {
        this.save(this.fileName);

    }
```

Es decir compruebas si existe un fichero llamado filename, que es un String (una vez más, quita esos **this** que no hacen nada) .
Si existe llamas a la funcion **save** y en caso contrario creas le dices al usuario que elija un nuevo fichero, así:

```
   FileDialog fileChooser = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Select save file", FileDialog.SAVE );
        fileChooser.setVisible(true);
        this.save(fileChooser.getDirectory() + fileChooser.getFile());
        this.text.setFileName(fileChooser.getFile());
```

Pero el nombre del fichero elegido por el usuario es guardado en text.setFileName. Dejando la variable fileName como estaba al principio.
¿ Me entiendes ahora ?
Tu código funcionaria si fuera algo asi:

```
public class SaveAction implements ActionListener{

private TextFile text;
// private String fileName; Lo quito pues no sirve para nada.

public SaveAction(TextFile textArea) {
    text = textArea;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Path path = Paths.get(text.getFileName());
    System.out.println(text.getFileName());
    if(Files.exists(path)) {
        this.save(text.getFileName());

    }
    else {
        FileDialog fileChooser = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Select save file", FileDialog.SAVE );
        fileChooser.setVisible(true);
        save(fileChooser.getDirectory() + fileChooser.getFile());
        text.setFileName(fileChooser.getFile());
    }

}

public void save(String fileName) {
    try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName, false));
    writer.write(text.getText());
    writer.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");

    }catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: pero si te fijas uso en openDocument el path completo que es lo que deberia guardarse en el TextFile, pero no se me guarda una vez utilizo el actionPerformed de save

Comment: Si, pero por un lado guardas datos en el String filename de tu clase save y, por otro lado guardas el nombre del fichero en la propiedad filename de tu clase Textfile. Vamos que lias una con otra.

Comment: aiii no acabo de ver a lo que te refieres porque creo que es lo mismo, yo cuando guardo sobre el de la clase TextFile es la qeu quiero que tenga el documento con el que trabajo ya que igualo punteros para que al modificar uno modifico el otro. Si me puedes marcar de alguna forma lo que dices te lo agradecería porque como llevo tanto tiempo mirando mi codigo puede que no lo vea de manera directa y por eso no entienda lo que dices! :(

Comment: Ya te he modificado la respuesta. Espero no haberme equivocado yo ;-)

Comment: tienes toda la razon, lo malo es que no acabo de entender por que no funcionaba de la otra forma si yo cogia de text igual el fileName. Voy a repasarlo bien. Muchas gracias, hay veces que cuando has escrito y mirado  tu codigo tanto es complicado encontrar errores aunque lo hayas ido limitando